# Is it possible to make an iframe truly responsive using HTML & CSS

Tags: iframe

I have some simple code for an iframe. I want to display a webpage within a webpage seamlessly i.e no scroll bar

I have tried hidden overflow but I just cant seem to get it right

HTML

```
 <iframe name="Framename"     src="https://website"
 width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" 
 class="frame- 
 area">
 </iframe>
```

CSS

```
.frame-area {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;  /* RESPONSIVE WIDTH */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;  /* EDIT TO hidden FOR NO SCROLLBAR */
  border: #999999 1px solid;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  }
```

The results I have is a full width page with only a small amount of height

I wish it to display full width and height and be fully responsive

Answer (score 0):

To make your iframe full height and width of your page use this css and iframe tag.

**[EDIT]** Due to your comment that there is a footer I have edited so it will work with a footer.  The footer disappeared because the iframe was 100% height and pushed it off at the bottom, which caused a scroll bar to appear. See below for the fix.

In the example code below, notice the CSS for the footer shows 30px height. So the iframe should be 30px less than the screen height to allow for the footer space. This is possible to do using height:calc(100% - 30px); of course substitute the actual height of your footer for 30px.

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.frame-area {
    position:absolute;
    height:calc(100% - 30px); /* example below if your footer is 30px in height */
    width:100%;
    border:none;
}

footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px; /* match this height in your iframe width calc value */
}
```

And with the CSS above, you can simplify the iframe tag's formatting:

```
<iframe name="Framename" src="https://website" class="frame-area"</iframe>
<footer>This is the footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thankyou, I have tried that and now my footer disappears and the scrollbar is there. Any help much appreciated

Comment: I edited my answer to allow for a footer.  Hope this helps.